# EclipseLink: Checking current transaction isolation level

Tags: java, jpa, transactions, eclipselink, jpa-2.0

I have a standalone Java application that uses EclipseLink 2.0.1. It is configured by a persistence.xml, and then does something like:

```
final EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("xy");
final EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
em.getTransaction().begin();
....
em.getTransaction().commit();
```

I want to find out, which Database Transaction Isolation level actually applies to that transaction. Even a "dirty debugging only" solution would be helpful.

The EclipseLink documentation [describes](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Using_Advanced_Unit_of_Work_API_%28ELUG%29#Database_Transaction_Isolation_Levels), that

> Achieving a particular database transaction isolation level in an EclipseLink application is more involved than simply using the DatabaseLogin method setTransactionIsolation

so I want to make sure, that my desired isolation level applies!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`Connection#getTransactionLevel()`](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#getTransactionIsolation%28%29) on the underlying `Connection` should work. Here is how you can get it with JPA 2.0:

```
final EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("xy");
final EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
em.getTransaction().begin();

java.sql.Connection connection = em.unwrap(java.sql.Connection.class);
System.out.println(connection.getTransactionIsolation());

....
em.getTransaction().commit();
```

#### Reference

- [Getting a JDBC Connection from an EntityManager](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/EMAPI#Getting_a_JDBC_Connection_from_an_EntityManager) (covers both JPA 1.0 and JPA 2.0)

Comment: Perfect answer! (I still had javax.persistence.1.0.x on my classpath for my test project, so I didn't see the unwrap method at all. Wouldn't have found it without your help. Thanks!)

Comment: Thanks also for the update - good to know, how to do it in JPA 1.0, too.

Comment: Yeah, especially since it's provider specific in JPA 1.0.